# cannot resolve mixpanel - after migrating to Android Studio

Tags: android, android-studio, dependencies, mixpanel

I tried migrating to Android Studio. When I use mixpanel project as library it works,but when I delete that folder and instead add in the build.gradle :

```
compile 'com.mixpanel.android:mixpanel-android:4.+'
compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services:3.1+'
```

it doesn't work , and says

```
import com.mixpanel.android.mpmetrics.MixpanelAPI; 
cannot resolve symbol mixpanel.
```

Comment: Clean, Resync gradle, Rebuild.

Comment: doesn't help .. have I missed something?

Comment: https://mixpanel.com/help/reference/android#installing-as
it says there something about `buildscript{..}`.. maybe I should add that somewhere?

Comment: yeah! i mean it's only library, you need to have ```repositories {
        jcenter()
        mavenCentral()
    }``` in buildscript { }

Comment: Do I need to add that in the project build.gradle( where the main activity is) or in the outer build.gradle?

Comment: It still doesn't work..

Comment: the project gradle you need to add.

Comment: I tried.. I'm still getting the same error

Answer (score 1):

compile 'com.mixpanel.android:mixpanel-android:4.+'

change to

compile 'com.mixpanel.android:mixpanel-android:4.9.1'

worked for me

Comment: worked for me too but how will we know when Mixpanel releases a new version? I haven't found a version number in their docs